# How can I solve a WordPress publishing problem?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

[image]I encounter a problem on WordPress as soon as I try to publish a page. A message appears telling me, t that the publication failed I do not understand I uninstall my extensions. and call 1 & 1, my host I have enough memory ... I even changed wifi connection, delete the images are useless but nothing helps. Help me, I beg you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and activate the Classic Editor plugin.
That'll help if you are using Gutenberg editor.

Comment: Thank you, it worked the update is done but it shows me a problem error 404. It says: The required file was not found. This may be a technical error. Please retry later. If you can not access the file after several attempts, it means that it has been deleted. While my link is good I have it checked

Comment: If you talking about the link to the page and its showing 404 while being published. Please re-save the permalinks in wp-admin->settings->permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

Enable DEBUG in wp-config.php
OR
Check the Apache and / or NGINX logs for a more accurate analysis of the error.